# Ruby localization

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to localize a web site, everything is almost done, except I have ran into two problems. The code below is for a small input form, but where are the strings? There is a label for a text field and a button.
Secondly, I am receiving an error:

```
"undefined method `-' for "translation missing: lv.date.order":String".
```

Where do i have to create the translation? In the .yml file? If so, how?
Thanks in advance!

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @publisher]) do |f| %>
  <% if @publisher.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@publisher.errors.count, t(:error)) %> <%=t(:prohibited_saved)%></h2>

      <ul>
      <% @publisher.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that Rails cannot find the translation for `date.order` in current locale file.

You should have a `lv.yml` file inside `config/locales` with this content:

```
lv:
  date:
    order:
    - :day
    - :month
    - :year
```

It will instruct rails to show dates in a format: `day/month/year`